# I am trying to setup android studio with offline setup. Does anyone have steps for it. I followed official documentation but no luck

Tags: android

Give me some suggestions as I am new to android.
I created projects using `Reactnative` and imported project to `andriodstudio`.

dependencies `{classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")}`. but my `andriodstudio` version is `3.4.1`

when trying to set up through offline mode using the below link I am getting sync failed
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Answer (score 0):

To do this effectively,

1.For first run, connect to network and build your project so that all your project dependencies are present in offline mode.

2. Then enable offline mode by settings -> gradle -> you can see offline mode option there and select it, Further
3. If you add any new dependency to you project you need to disable offline mode sync the project then again you can enable offline mode